# Kotlin vs. Java: Calling function with lambda parameter

Tags: java, lambda, kotlin

I am having this function defined in a kotlin file

```
fun loadSubmissions(projectId: Long?, completion: (List<Submission>, Exception) -> Unit) { ... }
```

And want to call it from Java like this

```
loadSubmissions(project.getProjectId(), (submissions, e) ->
    {
        updateSubmissions(submissions);
        return null;
    });
```

with

```
void updateSubmissions(List<Submission> submissionList)
{ .. }
```

But it gives me

```
Error:(226, 35) error: incompatible types: List<CAP#1> cannot be 
converted to List<Submission>
where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
CAP#1 extends Submission from capture of ? extends Submission
```

As I realize the parameter of the lambda function seems to be `List<CAP#>` instead of the expected and defined `List<Submission>`

If i convert the class to java, i can easily call that function with the lambda callback.

**What am I doing wrong**

Comment: I tried this: https://gist.github.com/jrtapsell/b05f83754ade9089fa371373d437b4c7 which seemed to work, could you see what the difference to your code is please

Comment: oh well.. sorry forgot a relevant part.. updating now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not disclosed the type of variable `submissions`, but the error message appears to indicate that it is `List<? extends Submission>`.  This is a different type from `List<Submission>`, and references of the former type are not assignable to variables of the latter type (though the other way around is ok).

That presents at least two problems for you:

- the lambda itself is not type-correct where it invokes `updateSubmissions()`, and
- the lambda's type, which comprises its parameter types, is incompatible with the type of the second parameter of `loadSubmissions()`.

To fix this, you need either to broaden the parameter types of those two methods or to narrow the type of variable `submissions`.

Comment: how to narrow down the type of `submissions` in the lambda block. If i specify it to `List<Submission>` like that `new Function2<List<Submission>, Exception, Unit>()` it says wrong 2nd argument type

Comment: There is no typesafe way to narrow the type of `submissions` *in the lambda block*.  It's type is determined by its declaration, and converting it to a narrower type requires a cast.  You could create a different object of suitable type, say by `new ArrayList<Submission>(submissions)`, but what I was suggesting was that you change the type of `submissions` in its declaration (if that's the alternative you select).

Comment: Mh okay, and why is it working like this with pure kotlin?

Comment: @martynmlostekk, that would depend on the kotlin use that works for you, and possibly on some kotlin-specific semantics.  I cannot speak to the details as you have not presented the relevant working source.  That anyway would be a separate question.